# Jquery Treemap not displaying all nodes

Tags: jquery, treemap

Here is the code to create treemap

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.treemap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="treemap"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#treemap").treemap({
                "nodeData": {
                    id: "root", "children": [
                        {
                            id: "NY",
                            size: [.8],
                            color: [1]
                        },
                        {
                            id: "NA",
                            size: [.8],
                            color: [1]
                        },
                        {
                            id: "SP",
                            size: [.6],
                            color: [1]
                        },
                        {
                            id: "NQ",
                            size: [.6],
                            color: [1]
                        },
                        {
                            id: "V",
                            size: [.6],
                            color: [1]
                        },
                        {
                            id: "R",
                            size: [.4],
                            color: [1]
                        },
                        {
                            id: "DJ",
                            size: [.4],
                            color: [1]
                        },
                        {
                            id: "BY",
                            size: [.6],
                            color: [1]
                        },
                    ]
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

when I run this page I can see only two bars NY and NA and others are not shown, not sure why it is so. I am using treemap for the first time so not actually clear on all the concepts. I have used their sample and it works but when I make changes as per my requirement it does not display.

Please advise why it is not displaying the other nodes?

Comment: are you using kendo ui treemap?

Comment: No, it is a jQuery treemap Plugin

Comment: can you share the demo site url?

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Treemap-Plugin-for-Hierarchical-Data-jsTreemap.html

Comment: issue is with your size value. The sum of  size value should not be greater than 1. I added the solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526818/6597375)

Comment: I am not sure that it should be always equal to or less than one as i see other examples also where the children sizes are also greater than one.. Can you send me the link where it says the size should be always less than one

Comment: Btw it shows NA and Ny whose sum is 1.6

Comment: treemap considering size as 1. So it will show the element based on the  size give. as you said the NY and NA has size '.8'. so  NY  will cover 80%(size .8) of  treemap and remaining(ie size .2 is remaining,  .8+.2=1)  only 20%. so NA will get only remaining 20%(size .2, but actual size of  NA is .8). Remaining .6 size of NA is not visible and  SP, NQ, V , R, DJ and  BY also not visible due NY and NA allocated with available size of 1.

Answer (score 1):

In nodeData, The sum of size data should be 1. In your question the sum is greater than 1. that is why you getting only first two portions(NY size .8 and NY Size .2 out of .8 (.6 of NA not visible)). If you giving the value of size with a sum of 1 the issue will solve.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#treemap").treemap({
            "nodeData": {
                id: "root", "children": [
                    {
                        id: "NY",
                        size: [.2],
                        color: [1]
                    },
                    {
                        id: "NA",
                        size: [.1],
                        color: [1]
                    },
                    {
                        id: "SP",
                        size: [.1],
                        color: [1]
                    },
                    {
                        id: "NQ",
                        size: [.1],
                        color: [1]
                    },
                    {
                        id: "V",
                        size: [.1],
                        color: [1]
                    },
                    {
                        id: "R",
                        size: [.1],
                        color: [1]
                    },
                    {
                        id: "DJ",
                        size: [.1],
                        color: [1]
                    },
                    {
                        id: "BY",
                        size: [.2],
                        color: [1]
                    },
                ]
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Treemap-Plugin-for-Hierarchical-Data-jsTreemap/js/jquery.ui.treemap.js"></script>
<div id="treemap"></div>
```